# Cannot provide coder for parameterized type org.apache.beam.sdk.values.KV<K, V>: Unable to provide a Coder for K

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am trying to group PCollection based on ids,but when I am using `GroupByKey.create()` its failing. I have already implemented `Serializable` interface for the class still issue is coming.
Its a simple logic, where I am grouping cards based on ids and printing the count.

```
PCollection<Card> cardPCollection = pubSubWindowed.apply(ParDo.of(new CardConversionFn()));
PCollection<KV<String, Card>> memberIdCardsMap = cardPCollection.apply((WithKeys.<String, Card>of(x -> x.getMemberId())));
PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<Card>>> memberIdCardList = memberIdCardsMap.apply(GroupByKey.create());
memberIdCardList.apply("PrintCollectionCount", ParDo.of(new DoFn<KV<String, Iterable<Card>>, Void>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                KV<String, Iterable<Card>> element = c.element();
                Iterable<Card> iterable = element.getValue();
                List<Card> cardList = new ArrayList<>();
                iterable.forEach(cardList::add);

                LOG.info("Printing Keys and Values {} {} {}",element.getKey() ,cardList.size(), cardList);
            }
}));
```

Comment: Can you please post the error that you are getting?

Comment: I suspect you can add `.setCoder(KVCoder.of(StringUtf8Coder.of(), SerializableCoder.of(Card.class))`, but without the error, it's hard to pinpoint the exact fix.